# In SAS, what does the option "dsd" stand for?

Tags: sas

I have a quick question.

I am learning SAS and have come across the `dsd=` option.

Does anyone know what this stands for?  It might assist in remembering / contextualizing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than just copy and pasting text from the internet. I'll try to explain it a bit clearer. Like the delimiter `DLM=`, `DSD` is an option that you can use in the `infile` statement.

Suppose a delimiter has been specified with `DLM=` and we used `DSD`. If SAS sees two delimiters that are side by side or with only blank **space(s)** between them, then it would recognize this as a missing value.

For example, if text file dog.txt contains the row:

```
171,255,,dog
```

Then,

```
data test;
    infile 'C:\sasdata\dog.txt' DLM=',' DSD;
    input A B C D $;
run;
```

will output:

```
                               A      B     C     D

                              171    255    .    dog
```

Therefore, variable `C` will be missing denoted by the `.`. If we had not used `DSD`, it would return as invalid data.

Comment: And, to answer the question, **DSD** stands for Delimiter Sensitive Data.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I wanted to know. Reminds me of those classic lyrics, "All I wanted was a Pepsi!"

Answer (score 9):

DSD stands for Delimiter-Sensitive Data.

> The DSD (Delimiter-Sensitive Data) in infile statement does three things for you. 1: it ignores delimiters in data values enclosed in quotation marks; 2: it ignores quotation marks as part of your data; 3: it treats two consecutive delimiters in a row as missing value.

Source: [easy sas](http://easysas.blogspot.com/2011/03/dlm-and-dsd-options-in-infile-statement_10.html)

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question, as to what the characters DSD refers to. I was looking for a way to memorize this and this helps.

Answer (score 8):

**DSD** (*delimiter-sensitive data*)

> specifies that when data values are enclosed in quotation marks,
>   delimiters within the value are treated as character data. The DSD
>   option changes how SAS treats delimiters when you use LIST input and
>   sets the default delimiter to a comma. When you specify DSD, SAS
>   treats two consecutive delimiters as a missing value and removes
>   quotation marks from character values.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm

Answer (score 0):

DSD refers to delimited data files that have delimiters back to back when there is missing data.  In the past, programs that created delimited files always put a blank for missing data.  Today, however, pc software does not put in blanks, which means that the delimiters are not separated.  The DSD option of the INFILE statement tells SAS to watch out for this.  Below are examples (using comma delimited values) to illustrated:

```
Old Way:    5,4, ,2, ,1    ===> INFILE 'file' DLM=',' ... etc
New Way:    5,4,,2,,1     ===>  INFILE 'file' DLM=',' DSD ... etc.
```

[Refer](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm)

[reference](http://studysas.blogspot.in/2008/08/options-in-sas-infile-statement.html)

Comment: Dude, you basically just copied and pasted everything from here: http://studysas.blogspot.com/2008/08/options-in-sas-infile-statement.html without mentioning the citations. Hence, your link is incorrect as it doesn't reflect to the correct source where you gained the information.